# Cart Throb for Expression Engine 3.0

Tags: cartthrob, ee3

Really dumb question but maybe even dumber issue with Cart Throb.

When you receive this error.

```
Error

Aromatic Binder is currently out of stock.
```

Where in the heck and how the heck do you add more inventory when there isn't any specific inventory management in 3.0

Answer (score 3):

From the CartThrob documentation.

> Decide whether or not you will manage inventory on an item-wide or
>   based on a specific group of item-options. Select the inventory field
>   in CT settings > product settings > product channels. Map your
>   inventory field to the field that will be used to track inventory. If
>   you haven't created an inventory field yet, just add a text field to
>   your channel fields for your product channel.

https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/pages/application_flow/#how-inventory-is-tracked